# Can the F# HtmlProvider access password protected pages?

Tags: f#, type-providers

I know how to grab data from a web page in F#...

```
let url = @"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who"
type DoctorWhoData = HtmlProvider<url>
let data = DoctorWhoData.GetSample()
```

...which is really neat, but I want to be able to do this for a password protected page. I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do this.

Anyone any suggestions? Thanks